# Como aumentar o tamanho da requisição GET para colocar parâmetros maiores que 10KB no NGINX e PHP?

Tags: php, nginx, get

Preciso fazer uma requisição GET muito grande com NGINX e PHP.
Existe alguma configuração no NGINX ou PHP que resolve isso?

Comment: Se você precisa mais do que 255 bytes o correto seria usar POST (ainda que navegadores suportem mais que isso). Olhe [a nota na especificação](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1). Por algum motivo o POST não funciona?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere a diretiva `large_client_header_buffers`.

> Directive assigns the maximum number and size of buffers for large headers to read from client request.
>
> The request line can not be bigger than the size of one buffer, if the client send a bigger header nginx returns error "Request URI too large" (414).
>
> The longest header line of request also must be not more than the size of one buffer, otherwise the client get the error "Bad request" (400).
>
> Buffers are separated only as needed.
>
> By default the size of one buffer is 8192 bytes. In the old nginx, this is equal to the size of page, depending on platform this either 4K or 8K, if at the end of working request connection converts to state keep-alive, then these buffers are freed.

Traduzindo:

> Essa diretiva atribui um número máximo e tamanho dos buffers para cabeçalhos longos lidos da requisição do cliente.
>
> A linha da requisição não pode ser maior do que o tamanho do buffer, e se o cliente enviar um cabeçalho o nginx retornará um erro do tipo "Request URI too large" (414).
>
> A maior linha do cabeçalho também não pode ser maior do que o tamanho de um buffer, caso contrário o cliente receberá um erro do tipo "Bad request" (400).
>
> Buffers são separados apenas se necessário.
>
> Por padrão o tamanho de um buffer é de 8192 bytes. No nginx antigo, isso equivale ao tamanho da página – dependendo da plataforma, é 4K ou 8K; se ao final da requisição atual a conexão adquirir o estado de keep-alive, então esses buffers são liberados.

Referência: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#large_client_header_buffers

Answer (score 1):

O tamanho máximo do GET é normalmente limitado tanto no servidor quanto no cliente, e esse limite costuma ser de 8KB. Se o cliente estiver passando por um proxy, provavelmente há um limite ali também. Ou seja, se você **precisa mesmo** de requisições GET maiores do que isso, vai ter que verificar as configurações de todos eles.